# Problems with subprocesses in python (pytest) (losing data that is being written to a file)

Tags: python, subprocess, pytest

I am in the middle of writing some a bit complicated test with python. It involves using subprocesses of the form

```
cpu_process = subprocess.Popen("sar -u 1 > cpu_usage.log", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                       shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

As you can see I am initiating a subprocess that fills a file with system activity data

so I do something like

```
def test_mytest(event_loop):
    event_loop.run_until_complete(run_command())
```

and the `event_loop` is like this

```
def event_loop(request):

    # run usage process
    cpu_process = subprocess.Popen("sar -u 1 > cpu_usage.log", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                       shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)

    with open("another.log", mode='w') as f:
        f.write("A log before tests\n")
        f.close()
        subprocess.run("df >> another.log", shell=True)


    setup()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop_policy().new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()
    teardown()

    # kill usage process
    os.killpg(os.getpgid(cpu_process.pid), signal.SIGTERM)

    with open("onemore.log", mode='w') as f:
        f.write("a log after tests\n")
        f.close()
        subprocess.run("df >> onemore.log", shell=True)
```

My problem is that the file `cpu_usage.log` gets created but its contents are nil (0 bytes). On the other hand both `another.log` and `onemore,log` gets the correct contents.

I am wondering why the subprocess is not working as expected. Can anybody advice me on that?

I suspect that the files are not being correctly closed, and therefore the files are left empty

PS. Recently in the `setup()` function there is another subprocesses but recently I have added the `subprocess.PIPE` there. Once before, when it did not have that the `cpu_usage.log` got the correct results

```
        subprocess.Popen(
            some_command, #some command
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE, # I added this recently 
             )
```

EDIT: When I interrupt the testing with Ctrl-C the file gets written with the correct results. This problem only happens when the test runs to its completion